# Column without name in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 4 `series` created by `counting` values in my DataFrame, which looks like

```py
hello world    2
aloha world        1
Name: hello, dtype: int64
```

I'm trying to `concat` these data to one `dataframe` like

```py
all_Data = pd.concat([series1, series2, series3, series4], axis=1)
all_Data .columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]
```

which create something like this

```py
Name: hello, dtype: int64
           col1  col2   col3  col4
hello world      2    0.0  0.0      0.0
aloha world          1    1.0  0.0      1.0
```

which creates 4 columns - for values, but there is not a column name for the first column `hello world` etc values.
I'm converting this `dataframe` to `dict` like

```
all_Data .to_dict(orient='records')
```

But there is not that first column with values (hello world, aloha world), how can I add that to the df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add reset_index() while concating the df.

all_Data = pd.concat([series1, series2, series3, series4], axis=1).reset_index()

then update the column names as you want:
all_Data.columns=[column_name1,column_name2,...]

Answer (score 0):

Pandas Series are a one dimensional labelled array. And here ***But there is not that first column with values (hello world, aloha world)*** the first column that you are referring to, is actually the label/index of the series. Now, ***how can I add that to the df?***. You can use `reset_index` function while concatenating the series to add this(index) as a column. After that when you convert the DataFrame to a dict, it will have the values.